# Updating post title using wp_update_post

Tags: custom-post-types, title, wp-update-post

I am creating a custom post type for a people page for a client website that has meta fields for both first and last name, but I would also like to update the title for the custom posts to be a combination of the two (i.e. "firstname lastname").

I am using `wp_update_post` to do this but am running into a problem. When I go to update a post, the data is updated correctly, but my cursor spins continuously and the page never reloads. I assume this is because `wp_update_post` is causing an infinite `save_post` loop, but [the recommended fix for this on the wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution.21) doesn't seem to be working and I assume there is a problem with how I am calling one or more function.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
add_action('edit_post', 'save_details');

function save_details($post_id){
  global $post;

      if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
              return $post_id;
      }

        update_post_meta($post->ID, "firstname", $_POST["firstname"]);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "lastname", $_POST["lastname"]);

        if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

            $args = array();
                $args['ID'] = $post_id;
                $args['post_title' ] = implode(' ', array($_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"]));

            remove_action('save_details','save_post');
                wp_update_post( $args );
            add_action('save_details','save_post');
    }

}
```

Comment: Just realized that the create a new post page for the custom type doesn't load either if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the parameters to remove_action are wrong, they should be *exactly* the same parameters that you used in add_action, first should be the hook and then the function name
`remove_action('save_post','save_details');`

Comment: that makes sense and I made the switch but the problem is still happening. Could there be another error as well?

Comment: you have an action hooked on edit_post. not sure where and when it is called. in addition you probably should not re-add the action after the update although I don't think it causes any harm.

Comment: the action on edit post was the issue, and when I added an extra remove action to account for it the problem was resolved.

I also took out the re-add action and it still works fine so I will leave it out